# Old wallet from old phone

Tags: wallet

I originally downloaded Bitcoin wallet app on an old phone that had broken, the incentive for downloading the app was one free Bitcoin. Is there any system files that I can find referencing the Bitcoin information from the app if I'm able to get back inside so I can transfer it?

Phone: Samsung Galaxy s2
App: Bitcoin wallet

Answer (score 1):

If you had saved "backup" of your wallet in a file with name similar to `bitcoin-wallet-backup-YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm`, it can be restored from SAFETY -> RESTORE WALLET on top-right in the app assuming you also remember the associated password for backup file.